# Concatenate Date objects onclick of h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.1.1. and very new to JSf in general.
I have two Calendar input fields on my form as such:

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="widgetFromDate" id="ID1" value="#{Bean.selected.From}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" mode="popup" showOn="button"> </p:calendar>

<p:calendar widgetVar="widgetFromTime" id="ID2" value="#{Bean.selected.Till}" pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" mode="popup" showOn="button"> </p:calendar>
```

I have a third field which concatenates and shows the above two values on the click of `h:commandButton`.

For example:

The button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Speichern" onclick="????"></h:commandButton>
```

I am not really sure how one accomplishes that. Could there be a possibility to use some ajax events?
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

-BR

Comment: Using "from" for a date part and using "till" for a time part is very strange and confusing, by the way. Try to make your code self-documenting by using sensible variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just basically so:

```
<p:calendar ... value="#{bean.date1}" />
<p:calendar ... value="#{bean.date2}" />
<p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" update="result" />
<h:outputText id="result" value="#{bean.date3}" />
```

with

```
public void submit() {
    date3 = mergeSomehow(date1, date2);
}
```

Or if you insist in using standard JSF command button, this has the same effect:

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="result" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Implementation detail of merging is up to you and not in any way related to JSF/PrimeFaces. Just ask a basic [java](/questions/tagged/java) question if you stucks.

The `onclick` attribtue is at least insuitable for this as it provides in this particular case merely a hook to execute some JavaScript function before the form is being submitted. You're not interested in this hook.

Comment: Though this answers my question, how would one implement the same logic with ajax for updating more than 1 resultant fields on the click of the button?

Comment: Just add its client ID space separated to update/render attribute. E.g. `update="field1 field2"`.

Comment: That said, I strongly recommend to look for a sane JSF tutorial/book. This is too basic. It's even mentioned in tag documentation itself.

Comment: Thanks again! That I shall do!